# Need to concatenate file names to a variable

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I want to concatenate the output of forfiles command to a variable. Find files older than 5 days then pass the file names to 7z command line to compress those files. This is what I have tried:

```
set filenames=
forfiles /D -5 /C "cmd /c set filenames= %filenames% @file"
echo %filenames%
```

This code did not work as the echo command output nothing. Need some guidance to achieve the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`forfiles` command](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) executes the command behind `/C` in a new `cmd` instance, therefore any environment changes like variables are not available in the hosting `cmd` instance that actually runs `forfiles`.

You could alternatively use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output echoed within `forfiles` and use this to build your variable:

```cmd
set "filenames="
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    forfiles /D -5 /C "cmd /C echo/@file"
') do (
    call set "filenames=%%filenames%% %%F"
)
```

The [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) is necessary here to be able to write *and* read the variable in the same (parenthesised) block of code.

Comment: I don't know that I can nest forfiles within for /F loop. Worked as expected. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You're welcome! You can capture the (console) output of any command line tool by `for /F`...